# is it possible to reverse engineer AOT angular build to source code in angular 6?

Tags: angular-cli, angular6, aot, ng-build

I lost my source code due to HD crash :(
I do have my uploaded Build of angular 6 project.
Is there any way to reverse those bundles to my source code ?

Please suggest related algos or any tools for the same.
it would be really helpful for all devs like me who have lost their codes